# How to import external NPM module with Typescript declarations using JSPM

Tags: typescript, jspm, systemjs

1. 'test-module' is external module written in Typescript with index.d.ts definition file. it has properties for tsd/tsc in package.json:

   "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
   "typescript": {
       "definition": "dist/index.d.ts"
   }
2. 'test-module' is installed with JSPM in jspm_packages/npm/test-module for dynamic loading using SystemJS
3. 'app' is Typescript application that imports 'test-module' like this:

   import {Component} from 'test-module';

The problem is that 'test-module' module HAS TO BE in both locations:

1. in **node_modules** for Typescript compiler (otherwise it does not find 'test-module' and errors it during compile import from 'test-module')
2. in **jspm_packages** for SystemJS to load it during runtime

So, i need to insert it in package.json 'dependencies' AND 'jspm/dependencies'

Is there a hack to :

A) force JSPM/SystemJS to use ONLY standard **node_modules** folder? (I know I can use raw SystemJS and map node_modules but it means that I have to map it for every single dependency and dependencies of dependency which is a lot of manual work)

**OR**

B) force Typescript to search modules using some kind of path mapping (I guess version 1.8 will have this feature)

Any ideas?

Comment: See here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513218/develop-npm-package-with-typescript-for-jspm-application/37513943#37513943) for my question or here (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6012) for the issue "automatic module resolution for JPSM packages".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a answer I don't like but is a work around. In fact I come across your question while searching for a answer to my case, they are similar.

In my case I create a external library too, that library is compiled with typescript and the module is generated to be consumed in external jspm projects.

What works for me is to import the library with the same syntax of javascript es6. Suppose the library is named myLib and have a config.js map of myLib=blabla and you have a file called notify.js (generated from typescript). The import is

```
import Notify from 'myLib/notify'
```

At runtime it works, but the problem is that the compiler for the project cannot locate 'myLib/notify'. The definition generated by typescript (file **jspm_package/github/myLib/myLib@version/notify.d.ts** for the library is something like:

```
export declare enum NotifyStatus {
    INFO = 0,
    SUCCESS = 1,
    WARNING = 2,
    DANGER = 3,
}
export declare enum NotifyPosition {
    TOP_CENTER = 0,
    TOP_LEFT = 1,
    TOP_RIGHT = 2,
    BOTTOM_CENTER = 3,
    BOTTOM_LEFT = 4,
    BOTTOM_RIGHT = 5,
}
/**
 * Class for notifications
 */
export declare class Notify {
    /**
     * Show a default Notification in the page
     * @param  {string}            message      The message
     * @param  {NotifyStatus   =            NotifyStatus.INFO} status   Status to style the message
     * @param  {[type]}            timeout=5000 Timeout
     * @param  {NotifyPosition =                                NotifyPosition.TOP_CENTER} pos        Position to display the message
     * @return {NotifyMessage}                  A object representing the message on the DOM
     */
    static show(message: string, status?: NotifyStatus, timeout?: number, pos?: NotifyPosition): NotifyMessage;
    private static getStatusString(status);
    private static getPositionString(position);
}
export interface DialogModal {
    show(): any;
    hide(): any;
}
```

To work around I manually modify the definition wrapping in a declaration of a library:

```
declare module 'myLib/notify' {
export declare enum NotifyStatus {
    INFO = 0,
    SUCCESS = 1,
    WARNING = 2,
    DANGER = 3,
}
export declare enum NotifyPosition {
    TOP_CENTER = 0,
    TOP_LEFT = 1,
    TOP_RIGHT = 2,
    BOTTOM_CENTER = 3,
    BOTTOM_LEFT = 4,
    BOTTOM_RIGHT = 5,
}
/**
 * Class for notifications
 */
export declare class Notify {
    /**
     * Show a default Notification in the page
     * @param  {string}            message      The message
     * @param  {NotifyStatus   =            NotifyStatus.INFO} status   Status to style the message
     * @param  {[type]}            timeout=5000 Timeout
     * @param  {NotifyPosition =                                NotifyPosition.TOP_CENTER} pos        Position to display the message
     * @return {NotifyMessage}                  A object representing the message on the DOM
     */
    static show(message: string, status?: NotifyStatus, timeout?: number, pos?: NotifyPosition): NotifyMessage;
    private static getStatusString(status);
    private static getPositionString(position);
}
export interface DialogModal {
    show(): any;
    hide(): any;
}
}
```

My **tsconfig.json** file is configured to look in jspm_packages for definitions

And then the compile stops warning and Atom editor provides intellisense.

There are two problems with this approach:

1. The wraps is made <strike>manually</strike> (this is annoying)
2. **myLib** is handwritten in the definition and can't be changed for other location, we must use import 'myLib/bla' and in reality 'myLib' can be overridden by SystemJS and jspm to other reference.

What I'm searching is a way to auto generate the typescript definition with the module declaration.

I came across this https://www.npmjs.com/package/autodts but I do not fully understand how it works, but it seams that can be use to automatically generate the definition file in this way.

Edit:

I create a gulp task to edit typescript definition files and add automatic add *declare module*. Here is how:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var paths = require('../paths');
var through2 = require('through2');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var insert = require('gulp-insert');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var merge = require('merge2');
var modify = require('gulp-modify');

var tsProjectAmd = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {module: 'amd'});
var tsProjectES6 = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {module: 'es6'});
var tsProjectCOMMONJS = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {module: 'commonjs'});
var tsProjectSystem = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {module: 'system'});

 var makeBuild = function(project, format, path, output){
  return function(){
    var tsResult =  gulp.src(path)
      .pipe(ts(project));
    return merge([
      tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest(output + format)),
      tsResult.dts.pipe(modify({
        fileModifier: function(file, content){
          // Split at /dist/ caracter
          var regex = new RegExp("/" + paths.dist);
          var split = file.path.split(regex);
          // Remove ".d.ts";
          var fileNameAndPath = split[1].slice(0, split[1].length - 5);
          if(fileNameAndPath != paths.packageName){
            return  'declare module "' + paths.packageName + "/" + fileNameAndPath + '" {\n' + content + '\n}';
          }else {
            return content;
          }

        }
      })).pipe(gulp.dest(output + format))
    ]);
  }
}


gulp.task('build-amd', makeBuild(tsProjectAmd, '', paths.source, paths.output));
```

paths.js

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var appRoot = 'src/';
var outputRoot = 'dist/src/';
var pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json', 'utf-8'));

module.exports = {
  root: appRoot,
  source: [appRoot + '**/*.ts','typings/**/*.ts'],
  html: appRoot + '**/*.html',
  style: outputRoot + 'css/**/*.css',
  styles: outputRoot + 'css/',
  less: ['less/theme/**/*.less','!less/theme/_variables.less'],
  fonts: 'less/uikit/src/fonts/*',
  images: 'images/**/*',
  output: outputRoot,
  doc:'./docs',
  apiDoc: './api-doc',
  dist: 'dist/',
  testsFixtures: 'test/fixtures/*',
  specsSrc: 'test/**/*.ts',
  specsOutput: 'dist/',
  packageName: pkg.name
};
```

Comment: that's exactly my current workflow. making 'module' wraps is annoying and error prone, i tried autodts but achieved nothing. i wonder how is your tsconfig.json configured so it looks for definition in jspm_packages? i wrote small plugin that generates tsd.d.ts //refences for jspm dependencies.

Comment: @Yoorek there is two ways of doing that in *tsconfig.json* one is use **"filesGlob": [
        "./**/*.ts",
        "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
    ],** another is use **"exclude": ["node_modules"],** the first works in Atom Editor, the second on anything

Comment: Yep, but i don't use Atom anymore (Visual Code is much better) and exclude is not enough

Comment: The exclude is a Typescript compiler config, the **filesGlob** is for editors. I use WebStorm, it look for the **files** array and all files have to be manually added, The atom editor reads **filesGlob** and edit **files**. Yes, it is a mess :-)

Comment: exclude works but is not enough (that's why Atom has fileGlob). e.g i don't want TS to include whole node_modules folders BUT i would like to include single package that has declarations inside. for that i had write my own plugin. TS should have 1. Glob setting in tsconfig. 2. path mapping for searching for modules (now it looks only in node_modules).

Comment: Atom Typescript is maintained by 1 (ONE) person and it's way worse than VS Code (and has a lot of bugs - there is no QA and tests, this guy publishes version every commit - I remember one day with 3 version...). But VS Code don't use any Glob setting. I got rid of Webstorm a year ago - it's slow (only Java can make my Macbook Pro 2014 hot as hell while indexing files ;-). it is a mess, big mess. But I think MS will clean it with TS 2.0 and VSCode 1.0 (they have plans and force to do it), so I am patiently waiting for better times ;-)

Comment: Good tip, I will check the VS Code. I use webstorm, actually intellij idea, because is one IDE for all my stack and is very powerful, but like to use less power consuming editors as well depending on the project

Comment: @Yoorek I update the answer with a gulp task that automate the process of writing definition

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime i ditched jspm/systemjs/gulp and switched to webpack - muuuch happier now